# Compilation error Problem with 10000 lines pas file in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe

I have a unit with 10000 rows for which I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924239/how-to-refactor-a-delphi-unit-with-10000-lines-with-no-documentation) in the past.

Anyway the problem now is that I just migrated from 2009 to XE. And everytime I compile that unit (or build my application) I get an error:

[DCC Error] 10000linesuni.pas(452): E2029 ',' or ':' expected but identifier 'dxBarLargeButton17' found

The workaround is to do a dummy modification to the pas file (add a '.' and remove it). Now it will compile correctly.

Is this a known problem? Does anyone know a workaround?

Note: I didn't have this problem in Delphi 2009.

This is the code you can see that 452 is nothing special, just one of the components on the form:

```
BarManagerBar4: TdxBar;
dxBarLargeButton16: TdxBarLargeButton;
dxBarLargeButton17: TdxBarLargeButton;  // This is line 452
dxBarLargeButton18: TdxBarLargeButton;
dxBarLargeButton19: TdxBarLargeButton;
dxBarLargeButton20: TdxBarLargeButton;
```

Comment: can you show the line 452 of your 10000linesuni.pas unit? are you check the encoding of that file?

Comment: What is the code at line 452?

Comment: another tip, sometime ago i have a similar issue and i use a hex editor to seek invalid chars.

Comment: @RRUZ - Following your tip I did CTRL - A, pasted in NotePad++, saved as 10000linesuni.pas again and now I was able to compile. Anyway should I feel ok now or I have to fear other problems? If you post as an answer i will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: NOT ONLY!!! Moreover now I can compare in JEDI VCS the different versions of the file. Before I couldn't becaue I got a CRC error. I thought his was related to a too long file. Delphi XE in 2 days helped me solving 2 problems I used to have in 2009. Very good.

Comment: CRC errors? Better change that hard drive *soon*.

Comment: It is a file in VCS, probably one developer with corrupted hard drive checked in this file, may be 2 years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

user193655, as the advice in my comment helped you, I will post as answer to help someone in the future to resolve this issue.

Sometimes the compilation of one or more files is interrupted due to the existence of invalid characters in the source code or mismatched line endings (should be CR/LF). To fix this use a hex editor to track the invalid chars and delete from the source file, or in the case of the line endings, open the file in Notepad, and save it; this fixes the line endings correctly.

Comment: @Ken thanks for the edit, personally i prefer to use the hex editor, `just to be sure`. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I prefer the opposite first. With a 10K line source file, a hex editor takes a while; trying the open/save in Notepad may fix it in a second. :)